# Labview Program changes behavior after looking at (not changing) the Block Diagram

Tags: labview

My Labview Program works like a charm, until I look at the Block Diagram. No changes are made. I do not Save. Just Ctrl+E and then Ctrl+R.

Now it does not work properly. Only a Restart of Labview fixes the problem.

My Program controls two Scanner arrays for Laser Cutting simultaneously. To force parallel working, I use the Error handler and loops that wait for a signal from the Scanner. But suddenly some loops run more often than they should.

What does majorly happen in Labview when I open the Block diagram that messes with my code?

---

Edit:
Its hard to tell what is happening without violating my non-disclosure agreement.

I'm controlling two independent mirror-Arrays for Laser Cutting. While one is running one Cutting-Job, the other is supposed to run the other Jobs. Just very fast. When the first is finished they meet at the same position and run the same geometry at the same slow speed. The jobs are provided as *.XML and stored as .net Objects. The device only runs the most recent job and overwrites it when getting a new one.

I can check if a job is still running. While this is true I run a while loop for the other jobs. Now this loop runs a few times too often and even ignores WAIT-blocks to a degree. Also it skips the part where it reads the XML job file, changes the speed part back to fast again and saves it. It only runs one time fast.

@Joe: No it does not. It only runs once well. afterwards it does not.

---

Youtube links

[The way it is supposed to move](https://youtu.be/10ZLZ4JS-l4)

[The wrong way](https://youtu.be/iyif5CA51eE)

Comment: Please, provide:
1. minimum reproducible VI
2. expected behavior
3. what do you see instead

Comment: Many things can happen. To be more precise try to describe the problem in more details or provide example code.

Comment: Is it also true that if you just open the VI and use Ctrl+R a few times that it always works correctly after the first run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the improbable case someone has a similar problem. The problem was a xml file that was read during run time. Sometimes multiple instances tried to access it and this produced the error.

Answer (score 3):

There is exactly one thing I can think of that changes solely by opening the block diagram.

When the block diagram opens, any commented-out or unreachable-code-compiler-eliminated sections of code will load their subVIs. If one of those commented out sections of code were somehow interfere with your running code, you might have an issue.

There are only two ways I know of for that to interfere... both of them are fairly improbable.
a) You have some sort of "check for all VIs in memory" or "check for all types in memory" that you're using as a plug-in system. When the commented-out sections load, that would change the VIs in memory. Such systems are not uncommon when parsing XML, so maybe. 
b) You are using Run VI method for some dynamically invoked VI to execute as a top-level VI, but by loading the diagram, it discovers that it is a subVI of your current program. A VI cannot simultaneously be top-level and a subVI, so the call to Run VI returns an error.

That's it. I can't think of anything else. Both ideas seem unlikely, but given your claim and a lack of a block diagram, I figured I'd post it as a hypothesis.

Comment: what is the best way to upload a block diagram in here? It is quite big with many Cases and sub-Vis

Comment: Posting a snippet image, as Mikhail suggests, works for the kinds of questions that StackOverflow is best for. But if you truly think you've found a bug in LabVIEW or need someone to investigate your whole hierarchy under an NDA, contact NI tech support. Their legal department can work with you to set up ways to investigate code without violating NDAs.

Comment: To create a snippet PNG, select the code on a block diagram that you want (it can be the entire block diagram) then choose from the menus Edit >> Create VI Snippet From Selection. This saves a .PNG file. You can view that PNG file online, but it has embedded metadata so that when a user drops that PNG on a block diagram, instead of just inserting a picture, it gets interpreted as a loaded VI and inserts the pictured code.

Answer (score 0):

Quick point to check: are Debug and "retain data in wires" disabled? While it may not change the computations, but it may certainly change the timing of very tight loops, and that was one of the unexpected program behaviors, OP was referring to.

Comment: checked that. its not that

Comment: Retain data in wires wouldn't change the behavior of running programs anyway. The values would be overwritten on the next execution. There's no feedback from the wire cache back into the program... caching off the wire values only helps with debugging by disabling a lot of LV's memory optimizations.

Comment: Retaining data in wires together with opened BD during the execution may skew off the timing of the parallel loops.Whether this is actually the case can be told only when the code is available.

Comment: Well, yeah, but anything can skew the timing of parallel loops... if you've written parallel code that is timing dependent, that's not a problem with opening the block diagram per se. :-)